# tabbar custom button image doesn't show up

Tags: swift, button, icons, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

I'm trying to display a custom button for the tab bar item in my Swift project.
I added a png file, called btn_new, to the Assets folder of the Xcode project and tried to display the custom button in the custom tabbar controller class. But I can only see a circle button with the default blue color and no custom image on it in my simulator.

[image]

this is the custom tabbar controller class.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var createEventViewController: CreateEventViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        createEventViewController = CreateEventViewController()
        self.delegate = self
        self.tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.customGreen()
    }
    
    func createListNC() -> UINavigationController {
        let listVC = listViewController()
        listVC.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "", image: UIImage(named: "btn_new"), tag: 0)
        return UINavigationController(rootViewController: listVC)
    }
    
    func setUpTabbarItems() -> [UIViewController]{
        return [createListNC()]
    }
    
}


extension CustomTabBarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
        if viewController == tabBarController.viewControllers?[0] {
            let vc = CreateEventViewController()
            let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
            nc.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
            self.present(nc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I double-checked the name is called exactly "btn_new", so I was not sure why the button is not displayed. Not really sure but, one thing I am concerned about is that I did not set a size for this custom icon. Can anyone tell me how can I display the button image for the tabbar item?

[image]

Comment: goto storyboard select tabBarItem and change image there

Comment: where you calling setUpTabbarItems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your CustomTabBarController viewDidload:

```
let buttonImage: UIImage! = UIImage(named: 
"btn_new")!.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
    (tabBar.items![0] ).selectedImage = buttonImage
```

Answer (score 0):

Goto Storyboard-> Select tabBarItem on VC(blue selected area)[image]